# Alterar a "collation" e "character set" da base de dados, tabelas e as colunas correspondentes

Tags: mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, collation

Alguns projectos mais antigos eram pensados no seu objectivo imediato e com base nisso as base-de-dados, tabelas e colunas eram preparadas de uma forma limitada ao cenário pretendido.

No sentido de actualização e adaptação para maior escalabilidade dos referidos projectos, temos vindo a actualizar as bases de dados para uma `collation` e `character set` com maior amplitude, como é o caso do `UFT-8`.

Até ao momento, tem sido realizadas consultas à base de dados para lidar com cada cenário:

**Alterar a tabela e seus campos:**

```sql
ALTER TABLE minhaTabela CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

<sup>Necessário ser executado para cada tabela existente, sendo aqui onde os lapsos ocorrem e todo o processo se torna extremamente moroso.</sup>

**Alterar a base-de-dados:**

```sql
ALTER DATABASE minhaBD CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Este processo é principalmente manual, requer uso de ferramentas que podem ou não ser do conhecimento da pessoa designada a realiza-lo e principalmente é moroso e sujeito a lapsos.

## Pergunta

Como proceder à alteração da `collation` e `character set` da base-de-dados, suas tabelas e respectivos campos de uma só vez?

Comment: Tente gerar um script a partir do Information Schema com o comando para cada uma das tabelas do banco.

Comment: Eu tenho esse script em SQL Server... uma pena!

Comment: @utluiz Será assim tão diferente de SQL Server para MySQL? Eu tenho ideia que a adaptação é _superficial_, mas não sou _expert_ em SQL Server!

Comment: Não é tão diferente. Fiz uma versão simplificada.

Answer (score 11):

Creio não haver um comando nativo que faça tudo, é possível criar uma query que faça o trabalho em seu lugar.

## Tabelas

Gerando as queries necessárias para cada tabela:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    "ALTER TABLE ", 
    TABLE_NAME,
    " CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;")
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
 WHERE TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA like '<schema>' 
   AND DATA_TYPE in ('varchar', 'text')
```

Agora é só copiar e colar. Note o filtro por `DATA_TYPE` para selecionar apenas os campos que possuam um collaction.

### [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcc28/14)

## Bases de dados

No caso das bases de dados, cheguei ao seguinte comando:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    "ALTER DATABASE ", 
    schema_name,
    " CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;")
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name LIKE '%'
```

### [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcc28/18)

Para automatizar o processo será necessário criar uma procedure ou script e executar cada comando com [`EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html).

Um modelo de procedure para ser usado como base pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379116/mysql-loop-through-databases-and-run-a-stored-procedure-on-it).

---

** Update **

Com as informações já disponibilizadas acima e com a [documentação de execução de queries dinâmicas](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), montei o procedimento abaixo para fazer a conversão automática dos bancos de dados e suas respectivas tabelas:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE change_collation()
BEGIN
  DECLARE db VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE tab VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE databasesCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT schema_name
      FROM information_schema.schemata
     WHERE schema_name LIKE '%';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


  OPEN databasesCursor;
  REPEAT
    FETCH databasesCursor INTO db;
    IF NOT done THEN

      SET @q = CONCAT(
            "ALTER DATABASE ", 
            db,
            " CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
      PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q;
      EXECUTE stmt1;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

      innerblock: BEGIN

      DECLARE tablesCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME 
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
         WHERE TABLE_TYPE = "BASE TABLE"
           AND TABLE_SCHEMA = db
           AND DATA_TYPE in ('varchar', 'text');
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done2 = TRUE;

      OPEN tablesCursor;
      REPEAT
        FETCH tablesCursor INTO tab;
        IF NOT done2 THEN

          SET @q = CONCAT(
                "ALTER TABLE ", 
                db, ".", tab,
                " CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
          PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q;
          EXECUTE stmt1;
          DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

        END IF;
      UNTIL done2 END REPEAT;

      CLOSE tablesCursor;

      END;

    END IF;
  UNTIL tablesCursor END REPEAT;

  CLOSE databasesCursor;
END//
```

Para executar a *procedure*, basta chamar assim:

```sql
call change_collation();
```

**Observação:** Eu não pude testar adequadamente o procedimento acima pois no SQLFiddle porque ocorre um erro. Obviamente eles não iriam permitir tais comandos no servidor.

### [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c77e9)

## Considerações finais

A *procedure* apresentada nesta solução irá listar os bancos de dados e suas tabelas, aplicando o comando de alteração em cada uma. Note, porém, que não há tratamento excepcional, então se houver algum problema, por exemplo relacionado à falta de permissão, a execução será interrompida.

É importante sempre considerar as permissões usadas para executar tanto a *procedure* quanto os comando executados.

Comment: A sugestão que estás a dar, se a leio correctamente, vai gerar uma consulta para cada tabela existente de forma a que faça um _copy&paste_ para as executar e alterar todas as tabelas, certo? Mas ficamos ainda "entalados" com a base-de-dados em si! Entendi bem?

Comment: @Zuul Não havia entendido o requisito completamente. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Boa parte do problema está resolvido, vou +1 pela ajuda e esperar a ver se algum iluminado, _ou eu_, aparece com a automatização de tudo isto! Tks.

Comment: @Zuul Ok. Agora tenho que ir, se não aparecer ninguém até a próxima semana eu faço a procedure. Abraço

Comment: @Zuul Terminei a procedure. Não tenho um MySQL para testar. Se não der certo, posso fazer alguns testes quando chegar em casa a noite.

Comment: Vou verificar do meu lado, mas só posso ver isto mais para o final da semana, dou feedback logo que o tenha!

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma solução com shell:

```
    DB="dbname"
(
    echo 'ALTER DATABASE `'"$DB"'` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'
    mysql "$DB" -e "SHOW TABLES" --batch --skip-column-names \
    | xargs -I{} echo 'ALTER TABLE `'{}'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'
) \
| mysql "$DB"
```

> Obs: Troque o dbname por sua database

Em uma linha de comando para copiar e colar:

```
DB="dbname"; ( echo 'ALTER DATABASE `'"$DB"'` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'; mysql "$DB" -e "SHOW TABLES" --batch --skip-column-names | xargs -I{} echo 'ALTER TABLE `'{}'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;' ) | mysql "$DB"
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873492/3130590